# Horizontal Separator for ToolStripDropDown list

Tags: c#, separator, toolstrip, toolstripdropdown

I'm creating a `ToolStripDropDownButton` with three `ToolStripButton`s. And I want to add a Separator after the second button.

Here's the code I have.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        internal ToolStripDropDownButton dropDownButton1;
        internal ToolStripDropDown dropDown;
        internal ToolStripButton buttonRed;
        internal ToolStripButton buttonBlue;
        internal ToolStripButton buttonYellow;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dropDownButton1 = new ToolStripDropDownButton();
            dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
            dropDownButton1.Text = "A";

            dropDownButton1.DropDown = dropDown;
            dropDownButton1.DropDownDirection = ToolStripDropDownDirection.Right;
            dropDownButton1.ShowDropDownArrow = false;

            buttonRed = new ToolStripButton();
            buttonRed.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            buttonRed.Text = "A";

            buttonBlue = new ToolStripButton();
            buttonBlue.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            buttonBlue.Text = "A";

            buttonYellow = new ToolStripButton();
            buttonYellow.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
            buttonYellow.Text = "A";

            ToolStripSeparator s = new ToolStripSeparator();

            dropDown.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { buttonRed, buttonBlue, s, buttonYellow });
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(dropDownButton1);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the Separator is displaying vertically.

[image]

How can I make it display horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `ToolStripDropDown`'s `LayoutStyle` property. By default it's `ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow`, but has to be set to `ToolStripLayoutStyle.VerticalStackWithOverflow`.

Alternatively, you can also skip creating and configuring a `ToolStripDropDown` instance and add the `ToolStripItem`s directly to your `ToolStripDropDownButton` using its `DropDownItems` property:

```
dropDownButton1.DropDownItems.AddRange(
    new ToolStripItem[] { buttonRed, buttonBlue, s, buttonYellow });
```